# Почему бизнес-логика имеет название "бизнес"?

Tags: java

Почему бизнес-логика имеет название "бизнес"?

Вопрос кажется глупый, но интересно понять логику. Ответьте пожалуйста, шире, чем одним словом и не ссылкой с википедии.

Comment: бизнес с английского - дело. то есть это значит, что имеется ввиду логика действий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Калька с английского. Правильно на русском - прикладная логика.

Answer (score 0):

бизнес логика - это понятие в каком-то контексте (список каких-то правил из узкой области вашего продукта)
Например вы копаете яму. Лопата - это внешние ресурсы и библиотеки. А сам процесс копания и есть бизнес логика.

Второй пример. У вас завод по производству лопат. 
В этом случае процесс создания лопаты - бизнес логика.